# How can I always get a good format for view page source?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, browser

I am trying to debug a problem, and I am using the `View Page Source` in `Chrome`.
A large portion of javascript and html is presented scrabled i.e. in a format with no identation and like:
`gt&blabla&gt`etc
Is there a tool/way to always get a good format of the generated source?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/315260/is-there-a-google-chrome-format-view-source-extension

Comment: opera dragonfly formats the code well and is a nice debugger for javascript

Comment: Maybe you want the DOM view instead. See https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements.

Comment: use this site to beautify your code http://ctrlq.org/beautifier/

Answer (score 3):

Open the developer tools: `Ctrl+Shift+I` or simply `F12`

You can see a nicely formatted and indented tree view of the source code under the `Elements` tab.

Comment: Except Inspector is always up to inserting elements that does not exists in the source, like JS-inserted stuffs, or just head/body tags even if they're not exists in the source. So, be extra careful, Inspector does not display you the source. Inspector displays what WebKit thinks about the code of the current page.

Answer (score 1):

If you hit F12 it will pull up the developer tools which gives you real good access to the source and scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can install chrome extension [Quick source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-source-viewer/cfmcghennfbpmhemnnfjhkdmnbidpanb)

- Once installed, click on the Extension icon (top right of chrome which looks like puzzle), and pin the `Quick source viewer` you just installed

  - This would make the icon appear on the top right
- Now, open any page you want to view the source of and click on the `Quick source viewer` icon
- You will see the page source opened that shows all the details in a better way

**Note:** If the icon doesn't work, restart chrome after installation